# Increment, Decrement, Remove and Count UI Functions :: Unfortunately not Working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, shopping-cart

Please see below my HTML and Javascript code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Shopping Cart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
        integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="top_nav">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo" />

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
            <a href="Catalogue.html">Catalogue</a>
            <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
        <span id="hamburger" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

        <div id="search_bar">
            <input type="search" placeholder="search..." />
            <button><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
        <!-- Created a shopping cart button that shows how many items are in the basket. -->
        <div>
            <a href="ShoppingCart.html" class="button" id="cart-button">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart"></i>
                <span class="amount-products badge badge-warning carttotal" id="lblCartCount" onchange="countCart()">0</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Created a <div> so that the page can be populated by dynamically created elements. -->
    <div id="populatecart">
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <p> &copy; Hyperion Development.&nbsp;&nbsp; All Rights Reserved.&nbsp;&nbsp; Proudly created by <a
                href="http://www.hyperiondev.com">Hyperion Development</a></p>
    </footer>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
// Navigation bar ***
// Function to display the side navigation area.
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}
// Function to close the side navigation area.
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

// Shopping cart ***
// Created a map array for items to be displayed in cart.
let cart = []
// Function to stringify and set items in local storage.
function saveCart() {
    localStorage.setItem("cart",
        JSON.stringify(cart)
    )
}
// Function to parse and get items from local storage.
function loadCart() {
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    if (cart === null) {
        cart = []
    }
}
// Called loadCart function.
loadCart()
// Created a constructor function to add items to the cart.
class Plant {
    constructor(name, image, price) {
        this.name = name
        this.image = image
        this.price = price
        this.count = 1
    }
}
// Created the new products and included the names, images and prices.
let plant1 = new Plant(
    "Agapanthus (Purple Cloud/ African Lily)",
    "images/Agapanthus.jpg",
    95,
);
let plant2 = new Plant(
    "Sweet Alyssum (Royal Carpet)",
    "images/Alyssum.jpg",
    25,
);
let plant3 = new Plant(
    "Clivia (Natal Lily/ Bush Lily)",
    "images/Clivia.jpg",
    95,
);
let plant4 = new Plant(
    "Dianthus (Ideal Select Violet)",
    "images/Dianthus.jpg",
    45,
);
let plant5 = new Plant(
    "Dahlia (Dreamy Eyes)",
    "images/Dahlia.jpg",
    40,
);
let plant6 = new Plant(
    "African Daisy (Bright Lights Yellow)",
    "images/Daisy.jpg",
    50,
);
let plant7 = new Plant(
    "Marigold (Honeycomb)",
    "images/Marigold.jpg",
    35,
);
let plant8 = new Plant(
    "Petunia (Supercal Neon Rose)",
    "images/Petunia.jpg",
    45,
);
// Created products array.
let myPlants = [plant1, plant2, plant3, plant4, plant5, plant6, plant7, plant8];
// Function to add and increase items in the cart.
function addCart(name, image, price) {
    // Looping through products in order to add or increase products.
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        if (cart[i].name === name) {
            cart[i].count += 1
            saveCart()
            return
        }
    }
    let plant = new Plant(name, image, price)
    cart.push(plant)
    saveCart()
}
// Function to remove and decrease items in the cart.
function removePlant(name, count = 1) {
    // Looping through products in order to remove or decrease products.
    for (let i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
        let plant = cart[i];
        if (plant.name === name) {
            if (plant.count > count) {
                plant.count -= count
            } else {
                cart.splice([i], 1)
            }
            break
        }
    }
    saveCart()
}
// Function to calculate discount total once a discount code is entered.
function calculateDiscount(discountCode) {
    if (discountCode === 'petals') {
        return 0.90;
    } else if (discountCode === 'flowers') {
        return 0.75;
    } else if (discountCode === 'fields') {
        return 0.5;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
// Function to work out the total costs of the items
function totalCart() {
    let total = 0
    for (const plant of cart) {
        total +=
            plant.count * plant.price
    }
    return total;
}
// Created function to store the amount of items in the navigation bar locally underneath the cart icon. 
 function countCart() {
     let count = 0
     for (const plant of cart) {
         count += plant.count
     }
     return count;
 }

function countCart() {
    let productNumbers = document.getElementById('cartquantity');
    if (productNumbers) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".carttotal").textContent = productNumbers;
    }
    saveCart()
}

// Function using the data attributes assigned in the product html pages to be able to add items by clicking the add-to-cart button.
function addVisualCart(plant) {
    let name = plant.getAttribute("data-name");
    let image = plant.getAttribute("data-image");
    let price = plant.getAttribute("data-price");
    addCart(name, image, price)
    alert(`${name} was successfully added to the cart. Your total is now R${totalCart()}.00`)
}

let quantity = 0;

document.getElementById('cartquantity').innerHTML = quantity;

function increaseCount() {
  document.getElementById('cartquantity').innerHTML = ++quantity;
}

function decreaseCount() {
  document.getElementById('cartquantity').innerHTML = --quantity;
}

let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.remove');
btns.forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', updateAmount);
});

function updateAmount() {
  var num = parseInt(document.getElementById('cartquantity').textContent.trim(), 10);
  this.value === "delete" ? num-- : num++;
  document.getElementById('.cartquantity').textContent = num;
}

// Function to generate a random order reference number when clicking on the "Confirm Order" button.
function submitOrder() {
    let orderRef = Math.random().toFixed(36).substr(2, 9);
    alert(`Thank you for your order. Your order reference number is ${orderRef}`);
}
// Function to display the cart items via the <div> "populatecart" that was created in the shopping cart's HTML page.
function displayCart() {
    let productContainer = document.getElementById("populatecart");
    let total = totalCart()
    if (addCart && productContainer) {
        Object.values(cart).map(item => {
            // Dynamically adding the items and elements to the HTML using the productContainer.
            productContainer.innerHTML += `
        <table class="products">
            <tr>
                <th class="cartimage productheader"></th>
                <th class="product-name productheader">PRODUCT</th>
                <th class="price productheader">PRICE</th>
                <th class="quantity productheader">QUANTITY</th>
                <th class="total productheader">TOTAL</th>
                <th class="remove productheader"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="productlist"><img src=${item.image} class="cartimage" alt="cartimage"></td>
                <td class="product-name productlist">${item.name}</td>
                <td class="price productlist">R${item.price}</td>
                <td class="quantity productlist">
                    <button id="increasecount" class="add" onclick="increaseCount()><i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i></button>
                    <p id="cartquantity" class="productcount productlist">${item.count}</p>
                    <button id="decreasecount" class="delete" onclick="decreaseCount()"><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td class="total productlist">R${item.price * item.count},00</td>
                <td class="productlist"><button class="remove" value="delete" onclick="removePlant()"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>`
        });
        // Dynamically adding the vat and other totals and select elements to the HTML using the productContainer.
        productContainer.innerHTML += `
        <form id="formcontainer"> 
        <div class="discount">
            <label id="discountlabel">Do you have a discount code?</label>
            <input id="discountinput" placeholder=" --- Enter code here ---"/>
            <button id="discountbutton" onclick="discountTotal()">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <label id="dropdownlabel">Is this for yourself or a gift for someone else's garden?:</label>
        <select id="dropdown">
        </select> 
        <div id="collectordelivery">
            <label>How would you like to receive your order?</label><br />
            <input type="radio" name="getitmethod" id="collection" value="collection" onclick="deliveryOrCollection()"/>Collection (Free of charge)<br />
            <input type="radio" name="getitmethod" id="delivery" value="delivery" onclick="deliveryOrCollection()"/>Delivery
        </div>
        <div id="deliveryoptions">
            <label>Select the preferred delivery option:</label><br />
            <input id="EcoD" value="15.00" type="radio" class="deliveryinput"/> Economy Delivery (5-7 working days) at R15.00<br />
            <input id="StdD" value="25.00" type="radio" class="deliveryinput"/> Standard Delivery (2-4 working days) at R25.00<br />
            <input id="ExpD" value="50.00" type="radio" class="deliveryinput"/> Expedited Delivery (1-2 working days) at R50.00
        </div>
        </form>
        <div id="vattotalcontainer"> 
            <h4 id="vattotaltitle">VAT:</h4>
            <h4 id="vattotal">R${total * 0.15}</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="baskettotalcontainer">
            <h4 id="baskettotaltitle">Total:</h4>
            <h4 id="baskettotal">R${total},00</h4>
        </div>
        <button id="submitorder" onclick="submitOrder()">Confirm Order</button>`
    }
}
// Function to calculate the discount total and to dedust this from the order total.
function discountTotal() {
    let discountCode = document.getElementById("discountinput").value;
    let total = document.getElementById("baskettotal");
    total.innerHTML = "R" + totalCart() * calculateDiscount(discountCode);
}

displayCart();


// jQuery ***
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.quantity').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $input = $this.find('.productcount');
        $this.on('click', '.add', function() {
          var val = parseInt($input.val());
          $input.val(++val);
        }).on('click', '.delete', function() {
          var val = parseInt($input.val());
          $input.val(--val);
        });
      });
// Created the dropdown options via jQuery with this function
    let myOptions = {
        select : '--- Please select ---',
        forme : 'This is for me.',
        gift : 'This is a gift. Please do not include a slip.'
    };
    let mySelect = $('#dropdown');
    $.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
        mySelect.append(
            $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
        );
    });

    // Created function to hide and show the delivery functions when someone selects either collect or delivery.
    $("#deliveryoptions").hide();
    $('input[name="getitmethod"]').click(function () {
        $("#deliveryoptions").hide();
        if ($('input[name="getitmethod"]').is(':checked')) {
            let radioValue = $("input[name='getitmethod']:checked").val();
            if (radioValue === "delivery") {
                $("#deliveryoptions").show();
            } else {
                $("#deliveryoptions").hide();
            }
        }
    });
});

//Created a function for the bee to "fly on the "Catalogue page".
$(document).keydown(function (key) {
    switch (parseInt(key.which, 10)) {
        // Left arrow pressed.
        case 37:
            $('.buzzerbee').stop().animate({
                left: "-=200px"
            }, 'fast');
            break;
            // Up arrow pressed.
        case 38:
            $('.buzzerbee').stop().animate({
                top: '-=200px'
            }, 'fast');
            break;
            // Right arrow pressed.
        case 39:
            $('.buzzerbee').stop().animate({
                left: '+=200px'
            }, 'fast');
            break;
            // Down arrow pressed.
        case 40:
            $('.buzzerbee').stop().animate({
                top: '+=200px'
            }, 'fast');
            break;
    }
})

// Created function to hide or show the product summary table on the "Catalogue" page.
$("#hide").click(function () {
    $("table").hide(1000);
});
$("#show").click(function () {
    $("table").show(1000);
});

// Created a chained function for the view our catalogue header on the "About Us" page.
$("#seeheaderbetter").click(function () {
    $("#viewcatalogue").css("color", "#05520f").animate({
            width: "100%"
        })
        //Enlarges the font size and makes the element bigger.
        .animate({
            fontSize: "46px"
        })
        .animate({
            borderWidth: 30
        });
});
```

I am trying to action the increment, decrement and remove functions, but am unfortunately not having any success. I was told that the increment and decrement functions can be actioned by calling the addCart and the removePlant functions, because they essentially do the same thing.

The functions should be executed by clicking on the respective buttons. I have tried adding eventListeners to the Javascript and by referencing onclick in the HTML elements, but nothing is happening. When I test addCart and removePlant in console.log it works perfectly. It is just to action it in the UI.

I am also having trouble populating the cart's badge counter, via the countCart function, on the navigation bar. I have tried the same as above (eventListeners and HTML onclick), as it should also be actioned by a button, but it is unfortunately not displaying.

I would appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction implementing these functions.

Comment: The `innerHTML` property of `cartquantity` will be a string - so `document.getElementById('cartquantity').innerHTML = ++quantity;` etc will not work. Perhaps try `document.getElementById('cartquantity').innerHTML = Number(document.getElementById('cartquantity').innerHTML ) + 1;` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the above mentioned issues, thanks to Professor Abronsius pointing out that it would be a string.

My solutions were as follows:

Javascript:

```
// Function using the data attributes assigned in the product html pages to be able to delete items by clicking the remove button.
function removeVisualCart(plant) {
  let name = plant.getAttribute("data-name");
  let count = plant.getAttribute("data-count");
  removePlant(name, count);
  countInCart();

  location.reload();
  alert(`${name} was successfully removed`);
}

// Created an increment function to amend the item count in the cart by clicking on the "up" arrow.
function increment(plant) {
  let name = plant.getAttribute("data-name");
  let image = plant.getAttribute("data-image");
  let price = plant.getAttribute("data-price");
  addCart(name, image, price);
  countInCart();

  location.reload();
}

// Created an decrement function to amend the item count in the cart by clicking on the "down" arrow.
function decrement(plant) {
  let name = plant.getAttribute("data-name");
  removePlant(name, 1);
  countInCart();

  location.reload();
}

// Created function to show the amount of items in the navigation bar on the cart icon.
function countInCart() {
  let productNumbers = document.getElementById("lblCartCount");
  if (productNumbers) {
    productNumbers.innerHTML = countCart();
  }
}
countInCart();
```

HTML:

```
<div>
            <a href="ShoppingCart.html" class="button" id="cart-button">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart"></i>
                <span class="amount-products badge badge-warning carttotal" id="lblCartCount" onchange="countCart()">0</span>
            </a>
        </div>

<td class="quantity productlist">
                    <button 
                    id="increasecount" 
                    class="add" 
                    data-name="${item.name}"
                    data-image="${item.image}"
                    data-price="${item.price}"
                    onclick="increment(this)"
                    >
                    <i class="fas fa-caret-square-up"></i>
                    </button>
                    <p id="cartquantity" class="productcount productlist">${item.count}</p>
                    <button 
                    id="decreasecount" 
                    class="delete" 
                    data-name="${item.name}"
                    onclick="decrement(this)"  
                    ><i class="fas fa-caret-square-down"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td class="total productlist">R${
                  item.price * item.count
                },00</td>
                <td class="productlist">
                <button 
                data-name="${item.name}"
                data-count="${item.count}"
                onclick="removeVisualCart(this)"
                class="remove" value="delete" onclick="removePlant()">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt">
                    </i> Remove</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I hope that this will help others that come across the same problems.